# Como sobrecargar con un parámetro un hilo en Android

Tags: java, android, hilos

Tengo esta clase donde crea un hilo:

```
 private class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            Log.d(TAG, "En ejecucion: " + HiloConsumo.getName() + " | " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
                sleep(1000); //pausa un segundo.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Le instancio de la siguiente manera en otra clase para poder usarlo:

```
HiloConsumo = new MyThread();
HiloConsumo.setName("Hilo Eduardo");
HiloConsumo.start();
```

Mi duda es que quiero pasarle un String desde la clase donde instancio y ejecuto el Hilo. He tratado de añadir lo siguiente en la clase del hilo:

```
public void run(String parametro){//HILO}
```

Y en el lugar que realizo la instancia pasarle el parametro:

```
HiloConsumo = new MyThread("entidad");
HiloConsumo.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como sobrecargar con un parámetro un hilo en Android.

Para inicializar con un valor precisamente se usa el constructor. Agrega un constructor que reciba el mensaje:

```
private class MyThread extends Thread {

    private String mensaje;

     // Constructor.
    public MyThread(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje= mensaje;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            Log.d(TAG, "En ejecucion: " + HiloConsumo.getName() + " | " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje: " + mensaje);
                sleep(1000); //pausa un segundo.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al instanciar el Thread puedes definir el mensaje:

```
HiloConsumo = new MyThread("Hola StackOverflow.");
HiloConsumo.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Crea una clase que implemente la interfaz [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) para luego crear un objeto de la clase Thread a cuyo constructor se le pasa un objeto de la clase creada anteriormente que implementa la interfaz Runnable.. No le pases parámetros al run() ya que es un método sobrescrito que es llamado por el start().

Ten en cuenta qué llamar al método run() de un objeto de una clase que implementa la intefaz Runnable NO crea un nuevo hilo de ejecución, sino que se ejecuta su código en el mismo hilo que ya se estaba ejecutando.

Un ejemplo:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Inicio 10 hilos que realizan 10 mensajes diferentes.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        // Creo el objeto mensaje.
        Mensaje msg= new Mensaje("Mensaje " + (i+1));
        // Creo un hilo que ejecute el objeto Mensaje.
        Thread thread = new Thread(msg);
        // Inicio la ejecución del hilo.
        thread.start();
    }
}

}

public class Mensaje implements Runnable {

    private String mensaje; 

    // Constructor.
    public Mensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje= mensaje;
    }

    // Método que ejecuta el hilo.
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // HAGO LO QUE SEA CON EL MENSAJE
       System.out.printf(mensaje);
    }

}
```